# How do you search for an object in a JSON file and then change the value of one of the key pairs?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "domain": "abc.com",
        "action": "no action",
        "date": "2020-05-15",
        "status": "new"
    },
    {
        "domain": "xyz.net",
        "action": "pending",
        "date": "2020-05-15",
        "status": "on-hold"
    }
]
```

I want to find abc.com and then change the value of action.

I've been able to find abc.com and print the action and I've been able to change the value of action for each object but I can't figure out how to change it for that one specific object.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What do you mean you are able to change it for each object but not that one specific object? Please see [ask] and [edit] your question with a [mre] of what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
json_ls = [
    {
        "domain": "abc.com",
        "action": "no action",
        "date": "2020-05-15",
        "status": "new"
    },
    {
        "domain": "xyz.net",
        "action": "pending",
        "date": "2020-05-15",
        "status": "on-hold"
    }
]
for i in json_ls:
    if "abc.com" in i.values():
        i['action'] = "New value"
```

New json_ls

```
[{'domain': 'abc.com', 'action': 'New value', 'date': '2020-05-15', 'status': 'new'}, {'domain': 'xyz.net', 'action': 'pending', 'date': '2020-05-15', 'status': 'on-hold'}]
```

This code will change the value of action in the dictionary was the "abc.com" is one of the values of the JSON/dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Leo Arad. That worked. I added a write statement to update the file:

```
import json

fhand = open("data.json")
data = json.loads(fhand.read())

for i in data:
    if "xyz.net" in i.values():
        i['action'] = "Takedown"

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```